# Sort objects based on property value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have Array of Objects, how can I go about searching all objects and categorise them based on property value

```
 data = [ 
  {key: 1, val: Mon, week: 0},
  {key: 1, val: Wed, week: 0},
  {key: 1, val: Mon, week: 1},
  {key: 1, val: Mon, week: 1}
  {key: 1, val: Mon, week: 2}
]
```

Desired output

```
week0Array = [{key: 1, val: Mon, week: 0},{key: 1, val: Wed, week: 0}]
week1Array = [{key: 1, val: Mon, week: 1}, {key: 1, val: Mon, week: 1} ]
week2Array = [{key: 1, val: Mon, week: 2}]
```

I have tried to use [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) in lodash kept getting undefined

```
_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])
```

Comment: How about just `weekArray[0]`, `weekArray[1]`, etc. Would that be acceptable? Also, are `Mon` and `Wed` supposed to be strings, or variable references?

Comment: hmm, it will not list all objects with `week: 0` for example

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I'm asking if the desired output can be adjusted to an array rather than separate variables.

Comment: Sure can! that would be better!

Comment: I don't think you want to "sort"; I think you want to "group".

Comment: Have a look at lodash's [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.groupBy(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) like this:

```js
let data = [ 
  {key: 1, val: 'Mon', week: 0},
  {key: 1, val: 'Wed', week: 0},
  {key: 1, val: 'Mon', week: 1},
  {key: 1, val: 'Mon', week: 1},
  {key: 1, val: 'Mon', week: 2}
]

let weekGroups = _.groupBy(data, d => d.week)

console.log(weekGroups[0])
console.log(weekGroups[1])
console.log(weekGroups[2])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that `weekGroups` is an `Object` and not an `Array`.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you want your end result to be sorted within the week arrays by the day, you will need to sort the individual arrays as well. The only reason Mon is before Wed in the weekGroups[0] is because that is the order it came into the function.

Comment: @KyleRichardson was that a comment to OP or did you want me to address that in my answer? OP didn't really request that, so, it's hard to tell if that was needed or not.

Comment: More of a comment to OP. I am assuming, ( I know dangerous right? ), that OP would like the weeks ordered by day within the week.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you can use the string predicate variant for grouping, `_.groupBy(data, 'week')`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a POJS alternative and assuming that the data is sorted to start with, reduce can create an array with the objects grouped into subarrays based on week. If sorting is required, it can be tacked on before the call to reduce:

```js
var data = [ 
    {key: 1, val: "Mon", week: 0},
    {key: 1, val: "Wed", week: 0},
    {key: 1, val: "Mon", week: 1},
    {key: 1, val: "Mon", week: 1},
    {key: 1, val: "Mon", week: 2}
];

var result = data.reduce((acc, obj, i) => {
    i && acc[acc.length-1].week == obj.week ?
        acc[acc.length-1].push(obj) :
        acc.push([obj]);

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

The brackets in the conditional `? :` aren't required but I think they aid readability.